# Query for Rollups/Features filtering by Parent

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I have a list of portfolio items that the user can click on, and when the user clicks on one, I want to query for the children of that item.  I have the initiatives separate from the the rollups which are separate from the features, and when it is clicked, I am getting the correct data.

However, When I try to query for its children, I run into problems.  Take the following example.

If a rollup was clicked on, I have tried these queries:

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
    type: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    success: function(model) {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model   : model,
            limit   : Infinity,
            fetch   : true,
            // filters : [{
            //     property : 'Parent',
            //     operator : '=',
            //     value    : rollup
            // }]
        }).load({
            callback : function(store) {
                console.log('got features');
                console.log('first feature',store.getItems()[0]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I run the query with the filters commented out as shown, then I get all of the features.  However, when I add in the filters, I get nothing back!  I have tried setting the variable Rollup to the rollup's ObjectID/name, and still nothing.  when I console log one of the features, I can see:

```
Parent: Object
    _rallyAPIMajor: "2"
    _rallyAPIMinor: "0"
    _ref: "/portfolioitem/rollup/xxxxxxxx"
    _refObjectName: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    _type: "PortfolioItem/Rollup"
```

and that is it.  Furthermore, I know there are portfolio items that meet the requirements I am trying to express in the filters. How can I filter out by parent when querying for portfolio items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I thought I had tried all possible combinations, but it appears that, even though it does not appear as a field when printed, the correct filter is:

```
filters : [{
    property : 'Parent.ObjectID',
    operator : '=',
    value    : rollup
}]
```